# JMETER - trying to test money values using beanshell

Tags: csv, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to execute tests using beanshell assertion. I have a csv file with Expected money amounts which are all to 2 decimal places eg 145.16, 1945.21 etc and i wish to compare them to actual values that will come back from my sampler http response with the same format. I wish my test case to pass if the difference between the two is < 0.1 i.e. 10 cents/pence etc.

I started by parsing the initial string values to doubles or floats or shorts and using Math.abs to compare but of course the accuracy was not there eg if the difference was actually 10 cents(FAIL) the calculation was actually be say 0.999999765 or similar and so the test case would incorrectly PASS.

I have now moved onto BigDecimal with little success. I have tried to use setScale which has made the comparsion a bit more accurate.

So my question is BigDecimal the way to go? What do i do with the BigDecimal after i have created it - if i convert it to a short or float etc i get the same problem again. Would DecimalFormat help ? I need the values to be with two decimal points at the point where i use Math.abs - is there an alternative to Math.abs ?

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. BigDecimal is quite good candidate to go with, at least all Java solutions which are designed to work with money objects are using BigDecimal under the hood. You may find [ROUND_HALF_EVEN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN) property useful
2. Be aware that there is [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) library which provides [Money.isGreaterThan()](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/apidocs/org/joda/money/Money.html#isGreaterThan-org.joda.money.BigMoneyProvider-) method which can be used instead of custom logic.
3. Starting from [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) [it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider switching to Groovy as soon as it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this worked for me in the end -

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

BigDecimal Actual_PAF = new BigDecimal("${Actual_PAF}");
BigDecimal Expected_PAF = new BigDecimal("${Expected_PAF}");

BigDecimal ActualPAFDifference = new 
BigDecimal(Actual_PAF.subtract(Expected_PAF).toString());

if (ActualPAFDifference.abs() < 0.001)

{ Failure=false;
  vars.put("PAFPassOrFail","PASS");}

else 
{ Failure=true;
vars.put("PAFPassOrFail","FAIL");
}
```